# How to use python and opencv to connect the selected points for gait analysis in an image/video

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do human leg gait analysis and I was able to connect only two points using Hough transform on a converted HSV image. As shown in figure 1[Two points connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDUAQ.jpg)  However I would like to connect all the four markers as shown [Image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Ml0.jpg). The code should then run on the video which I am assuming if it works on an image will work on the video as well. Any help or direction to look will be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some of the work that you've done in connecting two points? This would better facilitate an answer for your question.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out: highter resolution images, brighter lights and better targets will help by making the targets easier to detect more precisely. But beyond that you need to show an MCVE https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which exhibits the problem with linking up the targets.

Comment: I would use a tracker to collect the coordinate data for each of the points. After all of the data was collected, I would create the visualization. Post a video sample please.

Comment: When you see stories about motion capture for films, it is very common to see the subjects in uniformly dark suits with dots on the joints and filmed in a dark or green-screen environment - I would assume this is to make the challenge of tracking the dots easier. I imagine it makes it much easier than trying to capture from a casually dressed subject in a complex environment the whole picture having a range of colours and contrasts.

Comment: Actually, it won't work in code because of the pixel value in all the frames changes because of the lighting reflection as the legs move. Which is pointed out by @barny.   I did not post the code snippets as I had broken down the entire program into functions but I will keep this in mind in my future queries thanks

Comment: However @GenericUser if you are interested in seeing the code that I used I will be happy to post it in your inbox. As I have broken down it into functions so just posting a little bit of the snippet doesn't really make sense. I converted the image to HSV, then defined the upper and lower bound for the HSV value. Masked it and binary transformed it and finally joined the line using Hough Transform

Comment: You say "joined the line"? There isn't a line, only the point markers you are detecting? Please explain how you are using Hough to solve this problem?

Comment: @barny Yes, sorry I joined the points to form a line of units 15. These are the steps I followed. 1. Took a particular frame from the video.2.Convert it to HSV.3. Select and convert the particular HSV values to RGB and selected a particular range for pixel manipulation.4.Then I tried masking the particular area. 5 After which I used hough transform to get the bins with a vote of 7. Used those bin points as line coordinates and joined them. There were a lot many steps involved but this is the summary for the result you see here.

Comment: That sounds like a hard work way to join the markers - bones are rigid, they are linear between the markers, so if you are can detect the markers you can recreate the bones. So I don’t see why you introduce Hough.

Comment: @barny yes that exactly was the plan. To draw a rigid link between the markers. When I introduced Hough I got particular points on the marker which had the specific votes to be successful detected and mask all the other points. I could not find a better solution so I posted here for help? Do you have any suggestions I will be greatful

Comment: Ah you mean you are using hough to detect the X-shaped markers? That sounds like very hard work. My advice is to copy the professionals: give the model a dark head-to-toe suit, put some white dot markers on it at the joints (finding the centre of a dot is easy), video the person well-illuminated against a uniformly dark background - then when processing the video you can binarize the frame and get the dots very easily. Why make it harder? Garbage in, Garbage out.

Comment: @barny These were the equipment we had, unfortunately. We thought we will be able to detect it. I used binary transformation here as well but there was a lot of noise. So out of my current knowledge in open CV, this is the best result I came up with. I will keep further my knowledge base and see if I can come up with a fix

Comment: Given the quality of your picture/video, it may be far simpler to manually locate the markers every few frames. Good luck.

Comment: @barny I just used software called kinovea. It worked kind of although I wanted to develop my own program for it. But yeah sometimes it's about the learning that matters. This is what I say to console myself nowadays.